# Next.js - Head element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a quite simple Layout component that uses the `Head` component shipped with Next.js:

```
import React from 'react';                                                                                                 
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';                                                                             
import { Head } from 'next/head';                                                                                                                                                                                                         

import Header from './Header';                                                                                             

const Layout = ({ children }) => (                                                                                         
  <Container>                                                                                                              
    <Head>                                                                                                                 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css" />                 
    </Head>                                                                                                                
    <Header />                                                                                                             
    {children}                                                                                                             
    <h1>Footer</h1>                                                                                                        
  </Container>                                                                                                             
);                                                                                                                         

export default Layout;
```

That gives me an error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at invariant (/app/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2522:7)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2354:19)
    at renderToString (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2726:25)
    at renderPage (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:275:26)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/document.js:67:25)
    at _callee$ (/app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/utils.js:111:30)
    at tryCatch (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:12:30)
    at _next (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:9)
    at /app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:34:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/app/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)
    at /app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:7:12
    at loadGetInitialProps (/app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/utils.js:90:31)
    at _callee3$ (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:296:51)
    at tryCatch (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:12:30)
```

The error disappears if I don't use the `Head` component.

I can't find some related issue on Next.js page on Github and can't find something relevant on Google.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The error message says "You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports." Any chance it's the second option?

Comment: It's the component shipped with Next.js. It's not my component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the error message:

> You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined
>   in, or **you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

Here's an [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#populating-head) from their documentation where it looks like `Head` is a default export:

```
// yours (named import)
import { Head } from 'next/head';

// Next.js docs (default import)
import Head from 'next/head';
```

[More on imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Does updating your import fix this?

Comment: I haven't written the Head component by myself. It goes from Next.js

Comment: @user3309314 Look again at your sample code. `Head` is imported as a named import (`import { Head } from 'next/head'`). It's a subtle difference. Have you tried `import Head from 'next/head'` using default import yet?